# Why are the buttons not aligned?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code for a website, but the `<button>` elements in the center are too far up. Here's my code:

```css
h1
{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
/* Common Header */
body
{
 background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.header button
{
 background-color:#8C481B;
 text-align:center;
}
button
{
 display:inline-block;
 border-radius:15px;
 height:50px;
 width:125px;
 font-size:20px;
}
button span .comingsoon
{
 color:#eeeeee;
 font-size:10px!important;
}
nav
{
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <div class="header">
   <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><button type="button">Home</button></a>
    <!--First Case (unnamed)-->
    <button type="button" disabled><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
    <!--Second Case (unnamed)-->
    <button type="button" disabled><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
    <a href="help.html"><button type="button">Help</button></a>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- End Header -->
  <h1>Coming Soon!</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the buttons in the center are slightly higher. Why is this happening, and how can I align them correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra space in your CSS -- the "comingsoon" class is not being applied to your span;

Changing that from

```
button span .comingsoon
```

to

```
button span.comingsoon
```

Will fix the button alignment and font size mistakes.

Answer (score 22):

The default vertical alignment of inline elements is "baseline," which means the baseline of the element will be the same as the baseline of its parent.

If you add text to the parent element (`nav`), you'll see that the first word of each button sits on the same line as it:

[image]

To overcome this, set `vertical-align` of the buttons to "top" or "bottom":

```
button {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
h1
{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
/* Common Header */
body
{
 background-color: #d5d5d5;
}
.header button
{
 background-color:#8C481B;
 text-align:center;
}
button
{
 display:inline-block;
 border-radius:15px;
 height:50px;
 width:125px;
 font-size:20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
button span .comingsoon
{
 color:#eeeeee;
 font-size:10px!important;
}
nav
{
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <div class="header">
   <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><button type="button">Home</button></a>
    <!--First Case (unnamed)-->
    <button type="button" disabled><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
    <!--Second Case (unnamed)-->
    <button type="button" disabled><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span></button>
    <a href="help.html"><button type="button">Help</button></a>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- End Header -->
  <h1>Coming Soon!</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to reset `vertical-align` value :

```css
a,

button {

  vertical-align: top;

  /* or any other value that suits you */

}

h1 {

  text-decoration: underline;

}

/* Common Header */

body {

  background-color: #d5d5d5;

}

.header button {

  background-color: #8C481B;

  text-align: center;

}

button {

  display: inline-block;

  border-radius: 15px;

  height: 50px;

  width: 125px;

  font-size: 20px;

}

button span .comingsoon {

  color: #eeeeee;

  font-size: 10px!important;

}

nav {

  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <div class="header">
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">
        <button type="button">Home</button>
      </a>
      <!--First Case (unnamed)-->
      <button type="button" disabled><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span>
      </button>
      <!--Second Case (unnamed)-->
      <button type="button" disabled><span class="comingsoon">Coming soon!</span>
      </button>
      <a href="help.html">
        <button type="button">Help</button>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- End Header -->
  <h1>Coming Soon!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove blank space between `span` and `.comingsoon`

use : `button span.comingsoon`

Answer (score -2):

They are mis-aligned because the text is in multiple lines.

Try setting a smaller font-size, or seting a white-space:nowrap style to achieve one-line only text.

Alternatively, you can remove the width and let the buttons grow organically, based on the text within.

Comment: This circumvents the problem without solving anything.